# Facebook share parameters going wrong

Tags: php, facebook

I'm testing the fb sharer and get into trouble.
The Sharer took the summary parameters from the meta desc even when I'm heading it with a php condition.

PHP:

```
$actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
if($actual_link == "http://ormarketing.co.il/articles/view/{$id}")
{
    $selectd = $dba->query("SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE `id` = '" .$id. "'");
    $rowd = $selectd->fetch_assoc();
    $cont = stripcslashes(strip_tags($rowd['content']));
    $eh = '';
    $he = '';
}else{
    $eh = "<meta name='description' content='".$row['desc'].$r_art['tags']."'>
           <meta name='keywords' content='".$tag['tags'].$row['keywords']."'>";
    $he='';
}
```

to display it I used `echo`.

my share link:

```
    $str = urlencode(strip_tags(trim(substr($row['content'], 0, 100), '&nbsp;'))).'.....';
$titlee = urlencode($row['title']);
$actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
        <i class="fa fa-tags text-blue" aria-hidden="true"></i> שיתוף:   <a id="button" href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?s=100&p[url]={$actual_link}&p[images][0]=http://ormarketing.co.il/images/icon-fan.png&p[title]={$titlee}&p[summary]={$str}">d</a>
```

and in the share dialog printing the meta desc instead of the summary.
here is a link to view:

Comment: For debugging, have $actual_link printed to the page ... perhaps it's not what you think it is?

Answer (score 0):

As noted in [their response](https://developers.facebook.com/x/bugs/357750474364812/) on the Facebook Developers site, as of a couple years ago Facebook no longer supports the use of custom parameters for things like image, title, etc.

In order to customize these items, you need to specify them using the [OpenGraph meta tags](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/using-objects), such as `og:image`.

From there, the only parameter you need to pass to the Facebook sharer.php script is `u=[URL_OF_YOUR_PAGE]`.  (You should also pass the page URL through `urlencode()` before appending it to the Facebook sharer to ensure that you generate a valid URI.)